# iOS: Launching Messages app with multiple recipients

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sms

I'm trying to set it up so my user can send a text to a group of people. Now with email it's simple, the URL scheme is just `mailto://firstemail@email.com,secondemail@email.com` which can then be used with the `openURL` method.

Naturally when it came to SMS I decided to try `sms://2065555555,2061234567` however this doesn't work (it only adds the first number). After browsing Google a bit, I found some older threads claiming that texting to multiple recipients isn't possible using the URL method.

In order to send a message to multiple people, I've gone ahead and added `MessageUI` to my application, hooked up the `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate`, and now I can send indeed send messages to multiple people at once. However only from within my own application, which is not what I want. I was hoping there'd be something in the framework that would allow me to take advantage of the multiple recipients functionality and then launch it in the default messenger, but I can't find anything that allows that.

So, in short, is there *any* possible way I can code my app to populate the default Messages app with multiple recipients?

### Edit

Actually I'm certain there must be a way to do it, I just checked the app Cobook and they allow the user to select contacts then launch the Messages app sending a "New Group MMS".

Answer (score 10):

I realize this is a very old question - but I discovered the way to do it recently, and posted about it here:

[SMS WatchKit multiple number delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36575727/sms-watchkit-multiple-number-delimiter)

While this answer is watchkit specific, the url is really what you are asking about.

**ANSWER**:
I [found an obscure page](http://handleopenurl.com/scheme/apple-text) that gave me the answer. Turns out it is not documented by Apple anywhere I could find:

```
    let urlSafeBody = messageBody.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
    if let urlSafeBody = urlSafeBody, url = NSURL(string: "sms:/open?addresses=1-408-555-1212,1-408-555-2121,1-408-555-1221&body=\(urlSafeBody)") {
        WKExtension.sharedExtension().openSystemURL(url)
     }
```

The above version will open the messages app on the Apple Watch with multiple recipients pre-populated.

There are ***many pages*** that state it isn't possible, but it is. Hooray!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Added the details from that post.

Answer (score 0):

[Apple's documentation for the "`sms://`" URL scheme](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/SMSLinks/SMSLinks.html) seems to indicate only one phone number is possible within that URL.

The easiest thing to do here is to continue using MFMessageComposeViewController (which has a look and feel really close to the default Messages.app that people use to send and receive SMS messages).

And 
MFMessageComposeViewController has a [`receipients` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MFMessageComposeViewController/recipients) which is an array, which means you can have multiple destination phone numbers in your compose view.

Lastly, [here is a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818832/send-sms-to-mulitple-recipients) which covers a lot of the same ground you're thinking about here.

Comment: Thanks, as I stated in my post I already have the MFMCVC set up to send a text to multiple recipients. I would just prefer to launch the messages app, which I know it's possible since that's what Cobook does. I just don't have a clue how they did it.

Comment: Interestingly enough, [Cobook has an "open source" page on their website](https://cobook.co/open-source); but there's absolutely no documentation or helpful hints as to what's actually in there or whether or not it might help you.  Maybe it fulfills some license agreement, but it's less than useful and disengenuous on Cobook's part.