# SMS WatchKit multiple number delimiter

Tags: ios, swift, sms, watchkit, nsurl

I'm having a little trouble getting my WatchKit App to pre-compose an SMS message to multiple recipients (via the Apple Watch message app).

```
    let messageBody = "hello test message"
    let urlSafeBody = messageBody.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
    if let urlSafeBody = urlSafeBody, url = NSURL(string: "sms:8888888888&body=\(urlSafeBody)") {
        WKExtension.sharedExtension().openSystemURL(url)
```

My question is, if you have multiple phone numbers you want to send the message to from the watch, how do you delimit the values?

The SMS Links documentation entry does not explain delimiting to multiple recips from an NSURL.

I have tried:

```
NSURL(string: "sms:8888888888,9999999999&body=\(urlSafeBody)")
```

and

```
NSURL(string: "sms:8888888888;9999999999&body=\(urlSafeBody)")
```

but the message always shows up composed only to the first number.

Any help appreciated!

**UPDATE:**
[iOS: Launching Messages app with multiple recipients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23820570/ios-launching-messages-app-with-multiple-recipients) was linked in comments indicating that only one recipient is allowed in NSURL. This means I am trying to figure out any other way to send an SMS via watchkit... Not possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23820570/ios-launching-messages-app-with-multiple-recipients

Comment: @PetahChristian  That answer indicates NSURL cannot send to multiple contacts. Does this mean it isn't possible on Apple Watch?

Comment: @PetahChristian - is there a different means of sending a SMS message via WatchKit? Or am I stuck?

Answer (score 2):

I [found an obscure page](http://handleopenurl.com/scheme/apple-text) that gave me the answer. Turns out it is not documented by Apple anywhere I could find:

```
    let urlSafeBody = messageBody.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
    if let urlSafeBody = urlSafeBody, url = NSURL(string: "sms:/open?addresses=1-408-555-1212,1-408-555-2121,1-408-555-1221&body=\(urlSafeBody)") {
        WKExtension.sharedExtension().openSystemURL(url)
     }
```

The above version will open the messages app on the Apple Watch with multiple recipients pre-populated.

There are ***many pages*** that state it isn't possible, but it is. Hooray!

Thanks @petahchristian for the links, it led me down a google path to find this page.

UPDATE: for the sake of completeness - here is a related question I asked to get a fully functional multiple recipient pre-written sms from the watch to send. [AppleWatch Messages URL works hard coded but not with variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36601828/applewatch-messages-url-works-hard-coded-but-not-with-variables?lq=1)

Comment: I tried it on the watch and it send a message to the imaginary numbers in the answer. I am using real numbers to test now and will update with results.

Comment: @petahchristian - looks like it is working from the apple watch to send messages to valid numbers. I am not sure if you are still wondering since your comment is gone, but there it is! may be a limit on amount of numbers in the addresses though, exploring that now.

Comment: Nice find, interesting to note.

Comment: It shows the recipients by name if they are in the contacts, stacks up the names vertically above the message compose area. If the name isn't in the contact book it will stack the numbers up in the name's place. I have tried 6 contacts being added to the message (hard coded) and all have populated correctly. Seems like there isn't a limit (not tested). I am running into a new issue adding the phone numbers to the URL programmatically, though. When typed hard coded, it works. When adding the numbers via a variable it doesn't open the url. I will make  separate SO question to address that :(