# AppleWatch Messages URL works hard coded but not with variables

Tags: swift, apple-watch, nsurl

**TLDR** When I hard code phone numbers into a URL it opens in watch messages correctly, but when I use a variable string with the numbers typed in exactly the same way inside of it, it doesn't.

Example:

```
 NSURL(string: "sms:/open?addresses=8888888888,9999999999,3333333333&body=Test")
```

Above code works but below code doesn't:

```
 let hardCode = "8888888888,9999999999,3333333333"
 NSURL(string: "sms:/open?addresses=\(hardCode)&body=Test")
```

**FULL DETAILS:**
I am making a URL from variables to open messages on the Apple Watch with pre-filled contents. I am getting the phone numbers from the contact book and storing them in an array. They are provided in this format:

(###) ###-#### but need to be ##########

I tested the code by hard-coding phone numbers into the URL and it works properly with all contacts and completed body:

```
if let urlSafeBody = urlSafeBody, url = NSURL(string: "sms:/open?addresses=8888888888,9999999999,3333333333&body=\(urlSafeBody)") {
        print("FINAL URL: \(url)")
        WKExtension.sharedExtension().openSystemURL(url)
    }
```

But when I build the phone number values programmatically it does not work:

```
//holds phone numbers without special chars
    var tempArray: [String] = []

    //if I can access the unformatted numbers
    if let recips = saveData["recips"] as? [String] {
        //for each number provided
        recips.forEach { (person: String) in
            //remove all non-numerical digits
            //person is now (###) ###-####
            let newPerson = person.digitsOnly()
            //newPerson is ##########
            print(person)
            print("->\(newPerson)")
            //add formatted number to tempArray
            tempArray.append(newPerson)
        }

    }
    //combine all numbers with "," between as a string
    let recipString = tempArray.joinWithSeparator(",")
    //recipString contains ##########,##########,##########...

extension String {

func digitsOnly() -> String{
    let stringArray = self.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(
        NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet)
    let newString = stringArray.joinWithSeparator("")

    return newString
    }
}
```

I then add the "recipString" variable to the NSURL in the below code:

```
    let messageBody = "test"
    let urlSafeBody = messageBody.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())

    if let urlSafeBody = urlSafeBody, url = NSURL(string: "sms:/open?addresses=\(recipString)&body=\(urlSafeBody)") {
        print("FINAL URL: \(url)")
        WKExtension.sharedExtension().openSystemURL(url)
    }
```

The FINAL URL print shows the correct string, but the messages app does not open properly, and shows quick reply menu instead of composed message window. It matches the functioning hard coded number version exactly, but behaves differently.

Totally lost, hope someone can help!

**UPDATE 1**
Here are the debug prints for both versions of the URL:

Manually declared (not created from recipString but actually declared in the URL string explicitly):

This version works

> FINAL URL: sms:/open?addresses=0000000000,1111111111,2222222222,3333333333,4444444444&body=test

Variable created (using recipString):

This version doesn't

> FINAL URL: sms:/open?addresses=0000000000,1111111111,2222222222,3333333333,4444444444&body=test

I have also tried applying url encoding to the "recipString" variable by using the below if let:

```
if let urlSafeRecip = recipString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet()) {

        if let urlSafeBody = urlSafeBody, url = NSURL(string: "sms:/open?addresses=\(urlSafeRecip)&body=\(urlSafeBody)") {
            print("FINAL URL: \(url)")
            WKExtension.sharedExtension().openSystemURL(url)
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE 2**
I tested to see if the hardcode version of numbers matches the recipString exactly via this code:

```
    let hardCode = "0000000000,1111111111,2222222222,3333333333,4444444444"

    let isEqual = (hardCode == recipString)

    if isEqual {
        print("hardCode matches recipString")
    }
    else {
        print("hardCode does not match recipString")
    }
```

Debug prints:

> hardCode matches recipString

**UPDATE 3**

I have confirmed that:

When a URL is made with hard coded numbers vs. numbers that I make from variables, checking == between them returns true.

In every test I can do between the two version of the url, it matches.

**NOTES AFTER CORRECT ANSWER FOUND:**

This type of URL formatting will ONLY work with multiple addresses in the URL. If you do not have multiple addresses you will need to do the following, which is undocumented but none-the-less works. I found this by bashing my face on the keyboard for hours, so if it helps you an upvote is deserved :)

follow the answer marked below, and then use this type of logic check before making the URL in the doItButton() function he mentioned:

```
    func setupAndSendMsg(saveData: NSDictionary) {
    if let urlSafeBody = createBody(saveData) {
        let theNumbers = createNumbers(saveData).componentsSeparatedByString(",")
        print(theNumbers.count-1)
        if theNumbers.count-1 > 0 {
            if let url = NSURL(string: "sms:/open?addresses=\(createNumbers(saveData))&body=\(urlSafeBody)") {
                print(url)
                WKExtension.sharedExtension().openSystemURL(url)
            }
        } else {
            if let url = NSURL(string: "sms:/open?address=\(createNumbers(saveData)),&body=\(urlSafeBody)") {
                print(url)
                WKExtension.sharedExtension().openSystemURL(url)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you maybe share exactly what the `final urls` look like in both cases? you can redact the numbers

Comment: Yes - I will add an edit that shows the two print values as well as another format I've tried unsuccessfuly

Comment: Also, where did you find this URL format of opening up the SMS app? Apple officially only allows `sms:#-###-###-####` and I see somewhere ppl saying you can do `sms:#-###-###-####&body=xxx`.  Another weird thing about your URL is if this indeed was a valid URL scheme, why is there only one `/` after `sms:/` and not `//`?

Comment: After about a week of googlefu i found that format - it allows multiple recipients and works properly, if I can just resolve creating this url properly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36575727/sms-watchkit-multiple-number-delimiter/36579854#36579854

Comment: Sorry I can't try this myself, but can you try adding an extra `/` after `sms:/` so it becomes `sms://` and see if anything changes?

Comment: adding the / did not fix it :(

Comment: Hmm this is way too weird then. No more ideas :( maybe do a string compare just to check if they are _exactly_ equal. Hope someone else comes along with a solution!

Comment: I'd be wary of using an officially unsupported usage of the API, as Apple may break this functionality without warning in a future update. That said, I see you compare `hardCode` and `recipString`; do you compare the final URLs with `==`, to ensure no hidden characters/nulls? Also, if you encode your fully-specified URL into a variable, does that break as well, or is it only when you compose the string by interpolation? What if you interpolate other parts of the string than the addresses? What if you compose the string, then run the entire string through a character-by-character copy routine?

Comment: @palpatim - Does update 2 show you the comparison for hidden characters/nulls you are wondering about? I thought that update addressed your question and will change the code to test if it doesn't. Also, consider your warning well heeded about the usage of the unsupported code.

Comment: Update 2 compares the address portion of the string. I'm asking if you've tested other permutations using `==`, rather than relying on visual inspection (where it is easy to miss differences of whitespace or nonprinting characters). I'm also asking if you've varied the creation methods of your strings, and what the behaviors are in those cases. My read on your question and updates is that you haven't provided results for my specific questions. (Although you may of course have tried them while you've been banging on this problem.)

Comment: I should also clarify that I don't expect any particular result from this--I'm as puzzled by the apparent behavior as you are. I'm just suggesting other debugging tests to try and exclude programmer error.

Comment: @Palpatim I spent a few hours running every {==} test I can think of and it always passes as equal. Not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that it is not the acctual `openSystemUrl` call that is the problem. I believe there must be something with the code that is building the number string programmatically.

The code bellow is a simplified version of all the code you have posted. I have confirmed that it is working on my Apple Watch. It opens the Messages app with pre-populated numbers & body text.

Take one more look at your code and see if there is something your missing. If you can't find anything, just delete the code and re-write it, probably will be faster then spotting the weird issue.

Once again the code bellow is confirmed working as expected, so you should be able to get it to work. (or just copy & paste my code) :)

```
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

  @IBAction func doItButton() {
    if let urlSafeBody = createBody() {
      if let url = NSURL(string: "sms:/open?addresses=\(createNumbers())&body=\(urlSafeBody)") {
        print(url)
        WKExtension.sharedExtension().openSystemURL(url)
      }
    }
  }

  private func createBody() -> String? {
    let messageBody = "hello test message"
    return messageBody.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
  }

  private func createNumbers() -> String {
    let numbers = ["(111) 222-3333", "(444) 555-6666"]
    var tempArray: [String] = []
    numbers.forEach { (number: String) in
      tempArray.append(number.digitsOnly())
    }

    return tempArray.joinWithSeparator(",")
  }      
}

extension String {
  func digitsOnly() -> String{
    let stringArray = self.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(
      NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet)
    let newString = stringArray.joinWithSeparator("")

    return newString
  }
}
```

---

With above said I would recommend against using undocumented Apple features for anything you plan on putting on the App Store for the reasons already mentioned in comments.

Comment: After looking at my code countless times, and making sure I was "effectively" doing the same tasks your code shows, I was unable to make it work. However, I completely deleted and remade the code using function calls to create the two variables as you did, and now it works! There must be some sort of low level difference between the static variable and the one made by a function... Regardless THANK YOU! Wish I knew why it worked now considering it is almost identical - or rather why it didn't work to begin with.

Comment: Goblins, quite sure of it. :)

Comment: And the saga continues - this won't work if there is only 1 recipient number provided **pulls hair out and burns down house**

Comment: Added update to my question to address the comment I just made, with a working solution. Thanks again Mikael for the breakthrough today!

Comment: Glad you found a solution!