# multiple phone number sms link fails in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, sms

I'm working on a contact app that allows the user to start a group message to their friends.

I have a url like "sms:410-555-3029,630-555-9382" and it works on Android. When I press the link in the iPhone (iOS 11) It redirects to iMessage with just the first number: "410-555-3029,". All subsequent numbers after the first one are lost. I tried using "mms:" as a prefix, but that wasn't recognized.

Anyone have any idea how to create a group message link with iOS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this really took a lot of digging, but for iOS you can use the format:

```
"sms:/open?addresses=410-555-3029,630-555-9382"
```

I figure someone somewhere will need this, so I figured I'd post the answer.

**[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36575727/sms-watchkit-multiple-number-delimiter)**